# Retrieve values of each record in Json string

Tags: c#, json, loops

I have currently used the following code to retrieve the values of the first record in my Json string,

```
string JsonString = "{'response':[{'bigINT':123456789,'smallINT':12345},{'bigINT':00000000,'smallINT':00000},{'bigINT':999999999,'smallINT':99999}]}";
JObject Jobj = JObject.Parse(JsonString);

int firstbigINT = (int)Jobj["response"][0]["bigINT"];      // 123456789
int firstsmallINT = (int)Jobj["response"][0]["smallINT"];  // 12345
```

This works fine however I wish to iterate through all records using a foreach something like-

```
foreach (string record in Jobj)
{
    int bigINT = (int)Jobj["response"][0]["bigINT"];    
    int smallINT = (int)Jobj["response"][0]["smallINT"];

    use(bigINT,smallINT)
    // then go to next record 
}
```

as I need both the values together.

I tried using -

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(JsonString));

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.TokenType + " - " + reader.ValueType + " - " + reader.Value)
}
```

But this split the values one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
string JsonString = "{'response':[{'bigINT':123456789,'smallINT':12345},{'bigINT':00000000,'smallINT':00000},{'bigINT':999999999,'smallINT':99999}]}";
        JObject Jobj = JObject.Parse(JsonString);

        foreach (var response in Jobj["response"]) 
        {
          int firstbigINT = (int)response["bigINT"];
          int firstsmallINT = (int)response["smallINT"];
          use(bigINT,smallINT)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
object obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClassName>>(json .ToString());
```

This should work